# Coefficients: (5 not defined because of singularities)

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data

```
head(jobshop)
  X totalcost units goal.sd weight stamp chisel detail rush labor cost   lost  manager room.temp music shift mach.hrs plant breakdown rework
1 1  90751.53   423     0.1   4.48     4      7     No  Yes  1.47 4.71 0.8317     Alan     74.71  None     2    1.277   Old         1  0.114
2 2 100456.65   554     1.0   4.35     2      3    Yes   No  1.26 4.82 0.4951    Devon     75.37   Pop     1    1.317   New         0  0.000
3 3 128574.01   607     0.5   5.00     2      4     No   No  1.20 5.32 0.5584 Beatrice     75.29  None     1    1.071   Old         0  0.101
4 4  73996.67   347     1.0   5.39     2      4     No   No  1.46 5.44 0.4562  Ebrahim     75.27  Soul     1    1.375   New         0  0.000
5 5  98494.52   510     1.0   4.80     2      4     No   No  1.23 4.98 0.5018  Ebrahim     75.31  Soul     1    1.455   New         0  0.000
6 6  66745.85   419     0.5   3.99     2      4     No   No  1.21 4.60 0.4100  Ebrahim     75.38  Soul     1    1.065   New         0  0.000

my.fit <-lm(totalcost ~ units + goal.sd + weight + stamp + chisel + detail + rush + labor + cost +  lost + manager + room.temp + music + shift + mach.hrs + plant + breakdown + rework, data=jobshop)

goalfact <- as.factor(my.fit$goal.sd) 
stampfact <- as.factor(my.fit$stamp)
chiselfact <- as.factor(my.fit$chisel)
detailfact <- as.factor(my.fit$detail)
rushfact <- as.factor(my.fit$rush)
mgrfact <- as.factor(my.fit$manager)
shiftfact <- as.factor(my.fit$shift)
plntfact <- as.factor(my.fit$plant)
summary(my.fit)

Call:
lm(formula = totalcost ~ units + goal.sd + weight + stamp + chisel + 
    detail + rush + labor + cost + lost + manager + room.temp + 
    music + shift + mach.hrs + plant + breakdown + rework, data = jobshop)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-118706   -2007     286    2766   18836 

Coefficients: (5 not defined because of singularities)
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     -1.065e+05  1.493e+04  -7.129 3.73e-12 ***
units            1.913e+02  2.579e+00  74.151  < 2e-16 ***
goal.sd         -1.519e+03  1.208e+03  -1.257  0.20946    
weight           6.554e+03  5.787e+02  11.326  < 2e-16 ***
stamp           -1.412e+03  7.177e+02  -1.967  0.04972 *  
chisel           1.120e+02  5.057e+02   0.221  0.82487    
detailYes        6.880e+02  1.071e+03   0.643  0.52079    
rushYes          8.511e+02  9.893e+02   0.860  0.39006    
labor            1.112e+04  3.842e+03   2.894  0.00398 ** 
cost             5.920e+03  9.230e+02   6.413 3.40e-10 ***
lost             1.775e+04  6.871e+03   2.583  0.01010 *  
managerBeatrice  1.751e+03  1.235e+03   1.417  0.15714    
managerCarl     -1.137e+04  1.678e+03  -6.774 3.67e-11 ***
managerDevon    -1.164e+04  1.721e+03  -6.767 3.84e-11 ***
managerEbrahim  -1.107e+04  1.679e+03  -6.597 1.11e-10 ***
room.temp        2.108e+01  1.817e+02   0.116  0.90765    
musicPop                NA         NA      NA       NA    
musicRock               NA         NA      NA       NA    
musicSoul               NA         NA      NA       NA    
shift                   NA         NA      NA       NA    
mach.hrs         2.683e+04  1.870e+03  14.353  < 2e-16 ***
plantOld                NA         NA      NA       NA    
breakdown       -3.701e+01  9.261e+02  -0.040  0.96814    
rework          -8.327e+03  1.121e+04  -0.743  0.45795    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 8361 on 481 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.93, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9274 
F-statistic: 355.2 on 18 and 481 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Hi, I am taking a first course in regression and was trying to fit the above model. I tried to factor or make dummy variables of a few of the predictors but somehow I am getting the `Coefficients: (5 not defined because of singularities)` and `NA` for music and breakdown.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I am stuck!

Comment: I guess there is some collinearity in your data and based on the variable names which give the `NA`s, possibly some dummy variables are misspecified. What output dus `cor()` give for the variables? Also given the large size of some of your coefficients you might consider rescaling some of the variables. But that just a detail.

Answer (score 1):

1. You ran the regression before factoring anything. Your `my.fit` is still using unfactored data (the `goal.sd` instead of the `goalfact`).
2. You aren't using your factorized variables in your regression. `my.fit` is still referencing the old data.

Try running this instead:

```
    goalfact <- as.factor(my.fit$goal.sd) 
stampfact <- as.factor(my.fit$stamp)
    chiselfact <- as.factor(my.fit$chisel)
detailfact <- as.factor(my.fit$detail)
    rushfact <- as.factor(my.fit$rush)
mgrfact <- as.factor(my.fit$manager)
    shiftfact <- as.factor(my.fit$shift)
plntfact <- as.factor(my.fit$plant)

    my.fit <-lm(totalcost ~ units + goalfact + weight + stampfact + chiselfact + detailfact + rushfact + labor + cost +  lost + managerfact + room.temp + music + shiftfact + mach.hrs + plantfact + breakdown + rework, data=jobshop)`
```

You have singularities because some of your variables have perfect collinearity; some of your categorical variables occur together 100% of the time. For example, `plant = old` happens if and only if `music = none` / `rush = yes` if and only if `shift = 2`. You can (and should) remove one of these variables from the regression unless you can find more data where this doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks, now this:                                                                                                                        > my.fit <-lm(totalcost ~ units + goal.sd + weight + stamp + chisel + detail + rush + labor + cost +  lost + mgrfact + room.temp + musicfact + shiftfact + mach.hrs + plntfact + brkdnfact + rework, data=jobshop)
> goalfact <- as.factor(my.fit$goal.sd)                                                        Error in model.frame.default(formula = totalcost ~ units + goalfact +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'goalfact')

Comment: Can you see what goalfact is? (just do > goalfact)

Comment: It looks like you didn't change goal.sd to goalfact in the first part of your code; your error looks like your goalfact variable isn't what you want it to be.

Comment: I got it working now for some reason. Thanks for all your help @Kontorus